# How to get artifactId and version from pom in a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline plugin

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have set up Jenkins with the Multibranch Pipeline plugin, and I have configured it to trigger a build when there is a commit in a GitHub repository. I want to copy the `.jar` file, that is created by the maven build to a custom directory. To do that I have to specify the name of the file. The problem is that the name of the file contains the artifactId and the version from the `pom.xml` file. And the version changes quite often.

Is there a way to get the artifactId and version in Jenkins from the `pom.xml` file? I have red [this blog post](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/07/accessing-maven-project-properties-jenkins-build-jobs/), but it says that these Jenkins variables work only if I create a Maven project in Jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
pom.artifactId
pom.version
```

You will need [Pipeline Utility Steps plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Utility+Steps+Plugin) for this to work.